# How do I setup wxWidgets on Mac OS 9?

Tags: macos, installation, wxwidgets

Hi I would like to try out wxWidgets on Mac OS 9. Are there any directions on how to do this? I am looking at developing an application using the wxWidgets framework.

Comment: not really. Do you have experience working with the library? If yes - which OS?

Comment: Do you *really* mean Mac OS 9? Or perhaps macOS 10.9?

Comment: @igor - I read that wxWidgets (wxWindows) was available on Mac OS 8.6. See the December 11, 2001 report here https://www.wxwidgets.org/news/archive/.

Comment: @VZ - I do mean Mac OS 9 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

To target Mac OS 9 you will have to use an old (2.8 or maybe even earlier) Carbon-based wxMac version. Latest versions of wxWidgets use Cocoa and while 3.0 still includes Carbon support, it only targets 10.4 or later versions.

You will almost certainly need to find the corresponding vintage compiler to build it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I was able to find Codwarrior 8 Gold here: https://www.macintoshrepository.org/11910-codewarrior-8-gold